# Query for tag given slug

Tags: theme-development

How might I query for a tag given the slug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi **@JM at Work:**

Like this:

```
$term_slug = 'foo';
$term_object = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, 'post_tag' );
print_r( $term_object );
```

Comment: @JM at Work - Sure thing.